# Row is not populating

Tags: php

Trying to populate a row variable using a query, although it doesn't seem to be populating even know the code is correct.

The error message I receive is

> MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE RESOURCE, STRING

Any help would be appreciated

(I know I am using deprecated tags, don't worry)

Answer (score 1):

Before you fetch your results, you need to send query to db:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM event where event_id = '$eventselection'";  
$results = mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually running the query first, you are trying to fetch an array on the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because you're sending a string to mysql_fetch_array function, and that's wrong as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array).

You should do something like this:

```
$eventselection = 1;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event where event_id = '$eventselection'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       printf("Row column data here: %s", $row["nameOfYourColumn"]);  
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```